# How to add referenced library to Mave test

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

How can I add a referenced library (folder), with configuration files (log4j.xml, application.properties) to MAVEN test. The folders are referenced in Eclipse build path and the JUnit test cases can be run from Eclipse no problem. 
Executing MAVEN test fails, because it cannot locate these files.
Am using Eclipse Neon, JUnit 4, MAVEN 4

Comment: are they in src/test/resources ? that is where Maven will expect to find them.

Comment: do you really use maven 4 ???

Answer (score 0):

As jalynn indicated in his comment, simply create your test folders and files within `src/test/resources`. This picture was taken from IntelliJ and not Eclipse, but that's not relevant. The concept is from maven:

[image]

The files and folders within `src/main/resources` are accessible from the test classes too.

Comment: Did this help you.